# Save div on the server as image and download it

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.NET MVC application, in a div I have superpositioned images in to show how it seem an insole model.

I should download this image when the model is ready.

What I did works on my pc and download the image.

But when I publish the application, it opens the image instead of downloading it.

Any idea please ?

Here is what I did :

```
  Controller : 



    public JsonResult SaveModelImage(string dynamicImage)
    {
        try
        {
            var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dynamicImage.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
            //For capron modesls, there is more than one model with the same reference. For every model, must save image to the related folder.
            var imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10);

            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/MyApplicationRoot/Images/Temp/" + imageName + ".jpg"));

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromStream(ms, true))
                {
                    bmp.Save(imagePath);
                }
            }
            return Json(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootLink"] + "/Images/Temp/" + imageName + ".jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UserMethods.ParseError(ex, "UploadModelImage");
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }
    }




   HTMLCS :

       <a onclick="downloadImage()" class="download-image"></a>

       function downloadImage() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("reviewTopLeft1"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var tempcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            tempcanvas.width = 640;
            tempcanvas.height = 480;
            var context = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 640, 480);


            var val = tempcanvas.toDataURL();


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveModelImage", "Admin")',
                type: 'post',
                data: { dynamicImage: val},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (iudata) {
                    downloadURI(iudata, "Model.jpg");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    hideLoader();
                }
            });
        }
    });
   }


    function downloadURI(uri, name) {

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.target = "_blank";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;

   }
```

Comment: I think you might find some clues searching for "content-disposition" online.

Comment: Thankf for your advice Laurent S. I found this solution https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1156485/How-to-Create-and-Download-File-with-Ajax-in-ASP-N